# What's the term for duration minus drag in CPA?

Tags: critical-path

In Critical Path Analysis, does there exist an established term for the duration of an activity left over after subtracting the [drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_drag)? For example, if an activity takes 8 days and incurs 3 days of drag to the project, what would we call the remaining 5 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A.L. Steve Devaux here. It's an interesting question that I've never thought about! Tom Boyle (who pointed me here) suggests “critical concurrent duration”, which is pretty good. I think "multipath drag" might also be good, as it indicates that such time is delaying project completion, but is shared across more than one path.

It might be useful to compute the difference between "two-path drag" and "three-path drag". If Path A has a duration of 60D, Path B of 58D and Path C of 19D, you'd have:

One-path drag of 2D
Two-path drag of 58D-19D = 39D
Three-path drag of 19D

That would seem to me quite helpful in schedule analysis, pointing to a large opportunity to compress the schedule.

Fraternally in project management,

Steve the Bajan

Comment: Wow, quite a surprise! Thanks for your answer. I'll probably go with "critical concurrent duration" or "critical duration". Though, as you point out, "multipath drag" has the nice property of reminding people that we should consider the opportunities to shorten concurrent tasks too.